# how to empty plupload queue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, plupload

I am trying to empty the plupload queue, but it does not work. I have check a few SO questions and followed them but none work for me. Am i doing something wrong?

```
// Convert divs to queue widgets when the DOM is ready
$(function () {
    $("#uploader").pluploadQueue({
        // General settings
        runtimes: 'flash,html5,silverlight,browserplus,gears,html4',
        url: '<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~")%>Memories/HandlerAlbumUploader.aspx',
        max_file_size: '10mb',
        chunk_size: '1mb',
        unique_names: true,
        multiple_queues: true,
        // Resize images on clientside if we can
        //resize: { width: 320, height: 240, quality: 90 },

        // Specify what files to browse for
        filters: [
        { title: "Image files", extensions: "jpg,gif,png" }
    ],

        // Flash settings
        flash_swf_url: '<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~")%>Memories/js/plupload.flash.swf',

        // Silverlight settings
        silverlight_xap_url: '<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~")%>Memories/js/plupload.silverlight.xap',

        init: { StateChanged: function (up) {
            // Called when the state of the queue is changed
            if (up.state == plupload.STOPPED) {
                $('#<%=btnSubmit.ClientID%>').removeAttr('disabled');


            }
        }
        }
    });

    var uploader = $('#uploader').plupload('getUploader');
    uploader.splice();
    uploader.refresh();
});
```

Comment: "but it does not work" - not very helpful.

Comment: @MitchWheat actually nothing else happens.

Comment: How can this be flagged as Closed, it is a real question and I value the answer

Answer (score 3):

What you probably want to do is make a button or a link that when clicked will call `uploader.splice()`.

You'll also want to create a callback for the QueueChanged event (Use `uploader.bind()`), which will be fired by your call to `splice()`. Make this callback function clear/reset the UI elements that represent your queue.

Read the docs, all the information is there: https://www.plupload.com/docs/v2/Uploader